# sizeof operator macro #define MYSIZEOF(X) ((X*)0 +1)

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MYSIZEOF(X) ((X*)0 +1)
int main()
{
    printf("%ld", MYSIZEOF(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Can any one please explain how it works ?
thanks in advance

Comment: @ChrisBeck unrelated (that's finding the size of an array, where this code is finding the pointer to the PTE "iterator" of an implicit single-element array (which is valid in C++) but it tries to interprets the integral value of the resulting address...?)

Comment: @sehe yeah i realize that now, not actually any "sizeof" in there... time for sleep i think :X

Comment: Why the down votes ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz People tend to dislike [tag:c]/[tag:c++] double-tagging, and the sight of ` (X*)0` is a sign that this is needlessly flirting with UB. Also "what does this code do" without an idea is basically "dear lazy-web", could trigger some people. There's not a lot to love about this question, honestly (I didn't downvote)

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate duplicate. The duplicate only covers one small aspect related to this question

Answer (score 6):

The idea here is simple: arithmetic on a pointer to a type `T` is performed in multiples of the `sizeof(T)`, so `((X*)0 +1)` will - hopefully - be a pointer to an address `sizeof(X)` bytes into memory.

Unfortunately, the behaviour's undefined as `(X*)0` creates a NULL pointer, and the compiler may substitute some non-zero value used as that sentinel on the system it's compiling for.  Further, the code assumes `%ld` is the right format for a pointer, and it may not be.  `%p` would be an improvement if the `printf` implementation supports it.

Of course, it's silly not to use the `sizeof` operator directly....

Comment: And then, the integral value of a pointer might not lend itself to direct interpretation. Instead it could be compared to the nullptr again. I don't think taking the integral value of a nullptr is UB per se (but interpreting it is IB)

Comment: @venki Yes. It's just adding numbers on your implementation. Google "pointer arithmetics"

Comment: @sehe: *" I don't think taking the integral value of a nullptr is UB per se"* - but adding to it might carry it across a segment boundary or something... I believe that is undefined (you can only reason about pointer arithmetic within specific arrays, up until the one-past-the-end address).